# Change permalink structure ONLY for new posts

Tags: permalinks

I'm trying to find a way to change the permalink structure only on new posts that will come.

I did find [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191279/change-permalink-only-on-new-posts) where the solution says:

> Your permalink structure is global; it is not a property of individual posts. There is no way to indicate that one post uses a certain permalink structure while another uses a different one.

Contrary what above quote says I found this website that has old permalinks like this:

> http://www.decoist.com/2009-04-28/modern-quilt-sofa-by-ronan-and-erwan-bouroullec/

and the new ones like this

> http://www.decoist.com/porcelanosa-showroom-design-festival-valencia/

Do you have any ideas how it's done?

Thanks, friends.

Comment: I think they have just change the url using slugs

Comment: They've simply configured their URL rewrites to work with or without the date. `http://www.decoist.com/2009-04-28/modern-quilt-sofa-by-ronan-and-erwan-bouroullec/` loads the same content as `http://www.decoist.com/modern-quilt-sofa-by-ronan-and-erwan-bouroullec/`. In this case, it's still not a matter of old vs new.

Comment: @bosco They have these posts in the loop with the date until a certain point, after that they have without the date. I don't get it.

Comment: We'll need someone with more experience to answer definitively, but I might have misspoken, before. I believe that when you change your permalink structure after posting content with a different structure, post's old permalinks are actually stored in the post meta-data. WordPress has some logic pertaining to 404s - and maybe elsewhere - which will take into account the meta-data automatically in order to serve the old content from both the old and new addresses... I'd need to dig deeper to see how this all really works, but hopefully someone else is more familiar with it =]

Comment: This question is actually answered extensively in the link provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change permalink only on new posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191279/change-permalink-only-on-new-posts)